# TypeError seen when using ddf.read_sql_table - dask

Tags: dask, python-3.8

```
dask==2.27.0
python==3.8.3
Operating System== centos7
```

1. If its possible to pass sqlalchemy text which contains query for `ddf.read_sql_table`.
2. Seeing `TypeError` when parameters to read_sql_table are passed as mentioned in documentation.

Code:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
import dask.dataframe as ddf


DIALECT = '<value>'
SQL_DRIVER= '<value>'
USERNAME= '<value>'
PASSWORD = '<value>'
HOSTNAME = '<value>'
PORT = '<value>'
SID = '<value>'
ENGINE_PATH = DIALECT + '+' + SQL_DRIVER + '://' + USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD +'@' + HOSTNAME + ':' + str(PORT) + '/' + SID
s = text("My complicated sql query")
df = ddf.read_sql_table(s, ENGINE_PATH, index_col='id', npartitions=10)
```

Error seen:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/synology/data/ganesh/arun/code_jan_27/art_rematching/venv_3.8_50/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/sql.py", line 115, in read_sql_table
    index = table.columns[index_col] if isinstance(index_col, str) else index_col
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: I'm running into this issue too. Any luck?

Comment: I stopped using dask. I may be wrong, but too many things still to be sorted

Comment: yeah, it's definitely taking some getting used to on my end. I did come up with a solution to your problem - I'll post it in a response in case you ever circle back.

Answer (score 1):

So dask does not currently support complex queries directly in the text mechanism (as of v2021.02.0). My workaround is as follows:

1. Save your query as a view in the database
2. Construct the sqlalchemy uri string (as you have done in the question)
3. Initialize a "Table" object that points to your view
4. Pass everything to the read_sql_table function

See below for a simple example:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Metadata, Column, Integer
import dask.dataframe as ddf
import multiprocessing

uri = f'{dialect}://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{dbName}'
view = '[NAME_OF_VIEW]'
schema = '[NAME_OF_SCHEMA]'
pkey = '[PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN]'
myview = Table(view, Metadata(schema=schema), Column(pkey, Integer, primary_key=True))

df = ddf.read_sql_table(table=myview, uri=uri, index_col=pkey, schema=schema, npartitions=multiprocessing.cpu_count()*3)
```